# Switch on Motorola Moto G

Tags: motorola-moto-g, power-on

I have a motorola moto g, which power button has stopped working. My phone switched off, and now I'm not able to switch it on. I tried entering recovery mode but power button is needed, so it does nothing.

Also, when i connect the charger the screen switches on, and the percentage of the battery appears, also when connecting to PC.

Do any of you know any way to switch it on ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it does require a computer with the proper drivers loaded (if using Windows, Linux/Mac do not require special drivers) and fastboot installed (part of ADB package or mini-ADB & Fastboot)

1. Disconnect USB cable
2. Press and hold VOL DOWN and connect USB cable from computer
3. Continue holding VOL DOWN until the bootloader screen shows up then release button
4. On computer, use the command `fastboot continue` to boot the device

The device should go through it's normal start-up sequence now.

Comment: Wow that worked, i had lost all my hope!! Thank you very much