# How to boot with a volume button?

Tags: boot, motorola-moto-g, buttons, power-on, volume-buttons

I have a [motorola-moto-g](/questions/tagged/motorola-moto-g) which has a broken power button. I tried to fix my button by gluing it but now it seems that the button connection is somehow isolated and unworking completely, similar to that of [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/177298/202685). Now I need to find a workaround for being able to power my phone up if it shuts down.

I've researched about remapping volume buttons but most of what I've seen seem to work only on already powered up devices. I believe what I need is a lower level remapping. How can I remap volume up button so that it acts completely like the power button?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [here](https://www.techadvisor.co.uk/how-to/mobile-phone/how-to-turn-on-phone-without-power-button-3599004/), with some charge in your battery connecting to a PC or laptop via USB should work for Motorola Moto G. If this does not work for you try the below steps/solution.

Below methods will work depending on the make and model of your device; so no guarantees for the model you mentioned. However I personally have tried this on LG Q6 phone and it works for it. I assume it will work on other LG phones as well.

1. Plug your phone into the charger while it is shutdown. Some phones may  switch on this way.
2. Long pressing the volume buttons(try on both the buttons one at a time and if it does not work try both together). You might get a boot menu with instructions for navigation in the menu. Accordingly, select to power on the phone(system).
3. Connect to a PC or laptop via USB. I tried this with a my LG phone and it booted up instantly.

(LG 2017 and later models should be following the same firmware strategy so I am thinking it will work on all LG phones made in 2017 and later. I am writing this thinking it may be useful for LG owners facing similar issue)